# Postgresql Failed in Ubuntu environment. with error message - "socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

One day, My Postgresql server stopped working. Checked log. It was shutdown somehow.

```
root@ip_address:/# tail /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
2020-02-19 06:47:49.215 CET [23497] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2020-02-19 06:47:49.477 CET [23497] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 23512) exited with exit code 1
2020-02-19 06:47:49.482 CET [23507] LOG:  shutting down
2020-02-19 06:47:49.546 CET [23497] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

**When I run,**

```
root@ip_address:/# psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

It complained that there are no files and directory. so I checked if my `postgresql` running.

```
root@ip_address:/# systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2020-03-08 16:19:24 CET; 26min ago
  Process: 30136 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 30136 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 08 16:19:24 vps584959 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Mar 08 16:19:24 vps584959 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

It was running. but, if I check postgresql cluster.

```
root@ip_address:/# pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
10  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
```

It was **DOWN**

so I tried

```
root@ip_address:/# pg_ctlcluster 10 main start
 Error: Config owner (deploy:1003) and data owner (postgres:114) do not match, and config owner is not root
```

I wasn't able to make it work. then I tried.

```
sudo chown -R deploy:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/ && sudo chmod -R u=rwX,go= /var/lib/postgresql/10/
```

try again.

```
root@ip_address:/# pg_ctlcluster 10 main start
Job for postgresql@10-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
root@ip_address:/# systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service
● postgresql@10-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Sun 2020-03-08 16:59:53 CET; 2min 52s ago
  Process: 31635 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 10-main start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 23497 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 08 16:59:53 vps584959 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main...
Mar 08 16:59:53 vps584959 postgresql@10-main[31635]: Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -l /var/log/postgre
Mar 08 16:59:53 vps584959 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/postgresql/10-main.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Mar 08 16:59:53 vps584959 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Mar 08 16:59:53 vps584959 systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main.
```

Don't know what to do more. Is anybody had the same problem?

More infos.

```
root@ip_address:/var/run/postgresql# ls
total 0
drwxrwsr-x  3 postgres postgres   60 Feb 19 06:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 28 root     root     1060 Mar  8 13:58 ..
drwxr-s---  2 postgres postgres   40 Feb 19 06:47 10-main.pg_stat_tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pg_ctlcluster 10 main start
Error: Config owner (deploy:1003) and data owner (postgres:114) do not match, and config owner is not root
```

That's pretty clear, isn't it?

The Ubuntu PostgreSQL startup script wants that `postgresql.conf` and/or `pg_hba.conf` be owned by user `postgres`, else it refuses to proceed.

Comment: so what I did was 'sudo chown -R deploy:deploy /var/lib/postgresql/10/ && sudo chmod -R u=rwX,go= /var/lib/postgresql/10/'

Comment: but still having a problem.

Comment: One thing I would like to mention is.. in '/var/run/postgresql' folder. There is no PID file - 10-main.pid. Isn't this a matter? 

Will I lose my whole DB data?

Comment: But the config files are under `/etc/postgresql` in a normal Ubunto installation.